# Multiple materials on same object creating weird textures overlapping faces. Glitch or user error?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I recently finished a simple model and was practicing adding different materials. I have done this before and never ran into this problem. I created a material (bottle) and applied to the cylindrical shape. I then tried to create and apply the steel.001 texture to the face that is highlighted in the first image. I also applied this on several adjacent faces to better show the effect happening. I additionally tested applying the steel.001 green material to the long face to the right of the highlighted face.

I'm getting a strange result where the material is either overlapping onto other faces or not taking up the full face, which is something I haven't seen before. I'm not sure whether this is a glitch in my program, messed up setting, or a mistake I made, but I've opened and closed the program several times and gotten the same result.

[image: Water bottle]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're using a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. The modifier will move your edges once you'll apply it, but by default you'll continue to see their current position. But the material will be seen as if you applied the modifier:

[image]

If you enable the *On Cage* option of the modifier, you'll see the edges as they will be if you apply the modifier:

[image]

Comment: yes exactly, thanks!